# POST method not working in django, where i use Formview

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, backend

I have class where is use both, FormView and DetailView. when i send post request i see this log in terminal **[06/Apr/2022 14:44:16] "POST /profile/question/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6327**, but not working post, form_valid and form_invalid methods.
does not call these 3 functions and therefore the form is not stored

this is my code ->

```
class QuestionDetail(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Question
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "Profile/question_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "detail"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except:
            return redirect('Profile:error')

        self.get_object()
        return super(QuestionDetail, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.path

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        like_exist=bool(Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()))
        dislike_exist=bool(DisLike.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()))
        self.object=self.get_object()
        context = super(QuestionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            question = Question.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
            context['detail'] = question
            context['like_ex'] = like_exist
            context['dislike_ex'] = dislike_exist
        except Http404:
            return reverse("Profile:error")
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Not working post method")

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print("Error")
        return super(QuestionDetail, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("It's here")
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.question = self.get_object()
        form.save()
        return super(QuestionDetail, self).form_valid(form)
```

i don't understand what happened.

Comment: I think you are not calling these functions.

Comment: @HuzaifaZahoor what do you mean? i send post request, and i know that after automatically call these function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `post` method in your `dispatch` method:

```py
class QuestionDetail(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Question
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "Profile/question_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "detail"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.object = self.get_object()
        except:
            return redirect('Profile:error')

        self.get_object()
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.path

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        like_exist=bool(Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()))
        dislike_exist=bool(DisLike.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()))
        self.object=self.get_object()
        context = super(QuestionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            question = Question.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
            context['detail'] = question
            context['like_ex'] = like_exist
            context['dislike_ex'] = dislike_exist
        except Http404:
            return reverse("Profile:error")
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Not working post method")

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print("Error")
        return super(QuestionDetail, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("It's here")
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.question = self.get_object()
        form.save()
        return super(QuestionDetail, self).form_valid(form)
```

Now call `form_invalid` and `form_valid` in your implementation of `post`.

Comment: Yes it working, thank u. but i know that when you send post request, don't need to call manually. can u explain me?

Comment: @kokiwebaaa When you send a post request, the `post` method is automatically called by `dispatch`. If you override it, the default behavior stop working, so you need to call `post` explicitly in your `dispatch` implementation (you was calling get `instead`)

Answer (score 1):

More of a long comment than an explicit answer

It might be better to use `SingleObjectMixin` in conjunction with `FormView`. Inheriting from two complete CBV classes is probably not supported and might cause headaches after, for example, a Django verion upgrade. Whereas the `*Mixin` classes are intended to compound well.

The main thing you have to know about this is that `self.object` is not set by including the mixin. You have to explicitly set it, for example by subclassing the `setup` method:

```
def setup( self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super().setup( request, *args, **kwargs)
    self.object = self.get_object()  # link SingleObjectMixin
```

[Classy CBVs](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) in an invaluable resource for navigating  Class-Based Views